# How to tell eclipse java what to run

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse Java and am looking to finish my hello world tutorial but I'm not sure what packages to include in my app and Eclipse doesn't like that I don't have any packages specified. Any advice?

tutorial link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: All it is suggesting you to create package like "my.sample" and then create your source Java classes under that package. Since it discourages (doesn't stop) you to create java classes in default package.

Comment: Were you following an online tutorial? If so, please post a link to it so we know what you were doing...

Answer (score 1):

Look into this [Hello Eclipse](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html) example. It tell you how to code in Java using Eclipse (including creation of package and running it). Also, how to run the code from out side the Eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I do that tutorial, it says "Can't find [package].[class]"

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the `src` folder of your project and choose to create a new package. Give the package any name you want, for example `webnet.helloworldapp`. Then move your existing sources under that package with the `Refactor --> Move` command, or just manually add the following line to the files:

`package webnet.helloworldapp;`